# Renaming file in cmd through Teamcity declaring a variable.

Tags: batch-file, cmd, teamcity

I am running this script in teamcity cmd. I need to rename the file from users to users_date
I am using two %% to declare them as cmd parameters instead of Teamcity parameters.

SET TODAY=%%DATE:/=-%%

SET FNAME=User_%%TODAY%%.txt

ren User.txt %%FNAME%%.txt

When I run this through team city I get the following error:
The syntax of the command is incorrect.

Can anyone help me get the correct command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably, you'd need to use `%` in place of each `%%`.

It's possible that you also need

```
SET TODAY=%DATE:/=-%
SET FNAME=User_%TODAY: =0%.txt
ren User.txt %FNAME%.txt
```

where the `: =0` converts any spaces in the string `today` to 0s.

All depends on the exact format in which `date` appears. It depends on user settings, and may be in dd/mm/yy or mm/dd/yy form; with or without a dayname and may use leading-zero suppression (which I've assumed).

```
SET TODAY=%DATE:/=-%
SET TODAY=%TODAY:~4%
SET FNAME=User_%TODAY: =0%.txt
ren User.txt %FNAME%.txt
```

To remove the dayname, this form may be required - it removes the first 4 characters of the `today` (originally `date`) string.